# Snippet interface top padding

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design, stack-snippets

I'd seen snippet interface is updated and it looks good. But in case of snippet editor there is padding on each editor box it's really annoying.

[image]

It can be seen in the above image before the line number in each editor box.

Comment: Ya I agree, it is annoying, plus at least since the new update on stack snippet when trying to edited I can seem to edited the last lines, and I guess it is due to that padding

Comment: Yeah, I was going to post this, thanks for saving me the trouble. :-)

Comment: Turns out it [causes a bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326042/new-stack-snippet-cant-edit-last-lines).

Comment: This will be fixed, it's related to this [issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326042/new-stack-snippet-cant-edit-last-lines/326049#326049).