# New Stack Snippet can't edit last lines

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

After creating a snippet (with the new layout), when trying to edit, there are a few last lines that are impossible to edit, just because they don't show in the preview snippet to edit, although they are there, and if use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the <kbd>delete</kbd> key we can see they moved after inserting into post.

This was reproduces in FF47 using Windows

Can this be fixed?

Here's an example where this happens (copy to answer and edit to see the bug):

```html
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- This is the last line that you can't get to in the editor -->
```

Comment: Related (or probably duplicate, whatever): [*Snippet interface top padding*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326039/snippet-interface-top-padding)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes related as I pointed out in my comment there, but I don't guess would be a duplicate, but probably is that the reason for this to happen :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's now fixed and will be live after our next production build.

Comment: Good to know :) thanks!

Comment: It's live! ....