# New stack snippet doesn't show up last lines when editing until I hit Enter

Tags: discussion, support, bug, stack-snippets

**UPDATE**: The bug continues...

So I found this bug, *[New Stack Snippet can't edit last lines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326042/new-stack-snippet-cant-edit-last-lines)*, a few days ago when the new stack snippet was launched, and it was fixed right way.

However, at the moment, whenever I tried to edit some snippet, the last few lines won't show up until I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, even trying to do so some copy/paste, it will copy/paste in the wrong place

Can this be fixed?

Here is a snippet to test:

```html
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- scroll down -->
<!-- This is the last line that you can't get to in the editor -->
```

Comment: I just noticed that when scrolling down the text pointer goes *between* lines. There seems to be some issue between how the text is displayed and how the editor thinks the text is displayed... Like the displayed line height is a certain value, while the editor thinks it's slightly shorter.

Comment: Exactly @Bakuriu happens to me like that too

Comment: Looking at it. Meanwhile, as a workaround you can scroll down as much as you can in the editor, then place the cursor anywhere, then type anything and delete it. Now you can edit with no issues.

Comment: @Konamiman is there any update on this?